# What happens with Spark partitions when using Spark-Cassandra-Connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

So, I have a 16 node cluster where every node has Spark and Cassandra installed with a replication factor of 3 and spark.sql.shuffle.partitions of 96. I am using the Spark-Cassandra Connector 3.0.0 for doing a `repartitionByCassandraReplica.JoinWithCassandraTable` and then some SparkML analysis takes place. My question is what happens eventually with the spark partitions?

**1st scenario**

My `PartitionsPerHost` parameter of `repartitionByCassandraReplica` is numberofSelectedCassandraPartitionkeys which means if I choose 4 partition keys I get 4 partitions per Host. This gives me **64 spark partitions** because I have 16 hosts.

**2nd scenario**

But, according to the [Spark Cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) documentation, information from `system.size_estimates` table should be used in order to calculate the spark partitions. For example from my `system.size_estimates`:

```
estimated_table_size = mean_partition_size x number_of_partitions
                 = (24416287.87/1000000) MB x 332
                 = 8106.2 MB

spark_partitions = estimated_table_size / input.split.size_in_mb
             = 8106.2 MB / 64 MB
             = 126.6593 partitions
```

so, when does the 1st scenario takes place and when the second? Am I calculating something wrong? Is there specific cases where the 1st scenario happens and other cases the 2nd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are two completely different paths by which the number of Spark partitions are calculated.

If you're calling `repartitionByCassandraReplica()`, the number of Spark partitions are determined by both `partitionsPerHost` and the number of Cassandra nodes in the local DC.

Otherwise, the connector will use `input.split.size_in_mb` to determine the number of Spark partitions based on the estimated table size. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! So, if that is true then the repartitionByCassandraReplica is not affected or controlled by the directJoinSizeRatio. Right? Also, I am curious to see what happens with dynamic allocation and repartitionByCassandraReplica. Because somehow spark still has to decide how much resources it will use!

Comment: Do I have to enable SCC with .config("spark.sql.extensions","com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions") and set the directJoinSetting if I am going to use ONLY repartitionByCassandraReplica.JoinWithCassandraTable?? I see from SparkUI that regardless if SCC is enabled (also tried with directJoinSetting off or on) or disabled, a directJoin is always implemented! Is that correct?