# How is the input size calculated for repartitionByCassandraReplica.JoinWIthCassandraTable() vs DirectJoin=AlwaysOn?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

So I noticed that when calling `repartitionByCassandraReplica().JoinWIthCassandraTable()` gives me a different Input size in the Stages tab of SparkUI comparing to the one I get when the `DirectJoin` is always On. I know that these two follow different strategies of determining the Spark partitions:

When calling `repartitionByCassandraReplica()`, the number of Spark partitions is determined by `partitionsPerHost`. Otherwise, the connector will use the estimated table size. Nevertheless, as per documentation, both use `DirectJoin` and do not perform a full scan of a Cassandra table.

**In my case:**

With `DirectJoin` always On I get **36.9Gb** size in the Input column and it takes **4.5 minutes** for a Join and count. However, with `repartitionByCassandraReplica().JoinWIthCassandraTable()` on the same data I get **68.9Gb** (almost double) in **3.4 minutes**.

**Question 1**

How is the Input Column of Stages Tab calculated for each of these two Join strategies? Does the `DirectJoinAlwaysOn` uses the size of the estimated table size for input column and the `repartitionByCassandraReplica.JoinWIthCassandraTable()` the actual/precise size of the table?

**Question 2**

Why does `repartitionByCassandraReplica.JoinWIthCassandraTable()` take less time even if it has a bigger Input size? Is it just because of data locality?

**Question 3**

Finally, is the `repartitionByCassandraReplica().JoinWIthCassandraTable()` eventually affected by the size of the Cassandra table? Is the `DirectJoin` in these two different strategies a bit different (other than the how are the Spark partitions calculated) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input size is a derivative of the previous stage.

To answer your first question, the Direct Join setting has no bearing on how the Spark partitions are computed. What matters is whether you call `repartitionByCassandraReplica()` or not.

I've explained in your previous question ([What happens with Spark partitions when using Spark-Cassandra-Connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73686804/)) that the Spark partitions are computed differently by the Spark Cassandra connector depending on the APIs you're using. To summarise:

- IF `repartitionByCassandraReplica()` gets called, the number of Spark partitions are determined by both `partitionsPerHost` and the number of Cassandra nodes in the local DC.
- ELSE the Spark Cassandra connector uses `input.split.size_in_mb` to determine the number of Spark partitions based on the estimated table size.

Given that the number of Spark partitions widely differ between these two schemes, the resulting output size (data read) will widely differ too because the Cassandra token range(s) which get mapped to each Spark partition is also going to be different -- it's not an apples-for-apples comparison.

As a side note, I'd like to make a friendly request that you should limit to one question per post, particularly since your second and third questions are different from the original question. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will do so for the 2nd and 3rd question. Concerning the 1st question, the only previous stage I see in SparkUI before Join and Count is a map at RDDFunctions.scala:248 that usually takes from ms to 4 seconds. So I have 3 stages: this map, a count that performs basically the join and an actual count. I am just trying to understand how the size of the input column is connected with what the spark-cassandra connector sees. Even if I manage to have the same spark partitions between repByCassRep and DirectJoinAlwaysOn the input size is different.